# How could I solve this Dictionary problem in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

Being given the list of tuples `[("x", 3); ("num", 17); ("y", 7); ("x", 5)]` create a dictionary in which if there are equal keys their values are summed. So on this example, a dictionary like this should be created
`[("x", 8); ("num", 17); ("y", 7)];` it doesn't matter the order in dictionary.

This is the code I tried:

```
module MS = Map.Make(String);;
let f l = List.fold_left (fun acc (key, value) -> MS.add key value acc) MS.empty l;;
let f1 = f [("x", 3); ("num", 17); ("y", 7); ("x", 5)];;
MS.bindings f1;;
```

But it keeps overwriting the value of the same keys(the output is `[("num", 17); ("x", 5); ("y", 7)]`)

Comment: Where in your attempt do you do the summation?

Comment: `MS.add` inserts (ie adds) the `(key, value)` to the dictionary, it doesn't add multiple values together. When you insert a `key` that's already in the dictionary it is overwritten (hence the result you're seeing).

Comment: Maybe I didn't put the question wright way;

Comment: I don't know how to make the sum of the values so I just added them in the dictionary. How can I make the sum? (TY)

Comment: Use the `+` operator, e.g. `1 + 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Map's `update` function, not `add`:

```ml
module MS = Map.Make(String)

let f l =
  List.fold_left
    (fun acc (key, value) ->
         MS.update key (function Some v -> Some (value + v) | None -> Some value) acc)
     MS.empty l

let f1 = f [("x", 3); ("num", 17); ("y", 7); ("x", 5)]
```

With this version, `MS.bindings f1` will return `[("num", 17); ("x", 8); ("y", 7)]`.